# how to convert xml into list

Tags: python, list, xml-parsing

I have an XML tree like:

```
<abc>
    <cd>text1</cd>
    <cd>text2</cd>
    <ef>text3</ef>
    <ef>text4</ef>
</abc>
```

Now I want to save it as a list with tuples like: `[(text1,text3),(text2,text4)]` .

How do i do it?

Comment: Are you just trying to parse information out of the XML? If so a different approach completely may be better. There are XML parsing libraries available for Python, such as BeautifulSoup

Comment: i have tried using lxml library, but iam able to save it as `[text1,text2,text3,text4]`

Comment: read it as dicts then group by keys, there should be no problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
# import lxml.etree as ET   # also works

content = '''\
<abc>
    <cd>text1</cd>
    <cd>text2</cd>
    <ef>text3</ef>
    <ef>text4</ef>
</abc>'''

doc = ET.fromstring(content)
texts = (x.text for x in doc)
print(zip(*zip(*[texts]*2)))
```

yields

```
[('text1', 'text3'), ('text2', 'text4')]
```

---

Explanation:

You already know how to parse the XML into a list like this:

```
In [8]: [x.text for x in doc]
Out[8]: ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']
```

To group items by 2, use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), `zip(*[iter]*2)`:

```
In [11]: zip(*[texts]*2)
Out[11]: [('text1', 'text2'), ('text3', 'text4')]
```

Now you can use zip again to group the first items from each tuple, then the second items, etc:

```
In [14]: zip(*zip(*[texts]*2))
Out[14]: [('text1', 'text3'), ('text2', 'text4')]
```

Comment: stdlib is sufficient in this case: `import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET`